# realm テーブルの削除はできるでしょうか？

Tags: realm

Realmにテーブルを増やすためにはクラスを追加し、項目の増減を行うためには、クラス内のプロパティを増やしたり減らしたりすればいいのは分かったのですが、テーブルを削除する方法がわかりません。

クラスを削除し、バージョンを上げればRealmに反映されると思ったのですが、反映されないようなのでテーブルをRealmから削除する方法をご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

クラスをプロジェクトから消してもデータはそのまま残ります。
Realmは新しいクラスの追加や既存のクラスの更新は検知しますが、消えたクラスについては何もしません。

またテーブルという概念はRealmに存在しますが、テーブルごと削除するという操作は公開されていません。

同等のことを実現するにはそのクラス（＝テーブル）のデータをすべて削除するという操作になります。

```
try realm.write {
    realm.delete(realm.objects(TheTable.self))
}
```

のようになります。

Comment: Realmからテーブルを削除する（見えなくする）事は、不可能との理解でよろしいでしょうか。また、記載していただいたロジック（処理）は、C#でも可能でしょうか。可能でしたら、どのような構文になるか、お手数ですが、ご教授の程よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: > Realmからテーブルを削除する（見えなくする）事は、不可能との理解でよろしいでしょうか。

そうですね。どうしても消したければ新しいファイルを作って消したいテーブル以外のデータをコピーすると実現できます。

> C#でも可能でしょうか。

どのプラットフォームでも同様です。すべてのオブジェクトを取得してDeleteメソッドに渡します。

Comment: いろいろとご教授いただき、誠にありがとうございました。大変勉強になりました。